# Adding overflow: scroll only when the window size is 1366 * 768 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question, wanted to see if someone could shine some light on helping me with an issue that I have. The current companies intranet system is not responsive. Most employees are given a a bigger monitor so there isn't a big issue. There are a few employees who are using a laptop with a maximum resolution of 1366 * 768 and that is where the problem arises. When the user clicks a "button" a modal pops up, but since the intranet system is not responsive the bottom portion of the modal is not visible to the user. The only way for the user to see the bottom of the modal is to resize the browser window to below 75%. So the question is, is there a way to for me to add a overflow: scroll only if the window (browser window) goes below 1366 * 768. I don't want to add a scrollbar to the modal since the modal is perfectly viewable on bigger screens.

See CSS code below.

```
#divProductDetailsModal{
width: 1280px;
height: 662px;
margin-left: -640px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -360px;
/*overflow: scroll;*/
background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5 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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(204,204,204,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
border: 0;
```

}

Comment: Just use % on your modal dimensions ... and add overflow auto ??? ... please include your relevant code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 media queries to detect the size of the window:

```
@media (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {
    #divProductDetailsModal {
        overflow: scroll;

        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

When the screen size gets small, the modal should be flexible-sized so scrolling is possible. You won't be able to scroll on something that has a fixed size. Making the modal flexible-sized will also allow it to fit for users with a screen **even smaller** than 1366 x 768.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using media query, just add a few lines to the CSS.

Or you can get the window size with js and once it gets below 1366 * 768 add some style to it.

Media query is easier.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) , screen and (max-height: 768px) {
  #divProductDetailsModal {
     overflow: scroll;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mediaqueries it's better if you define your dimensions and positions in `%`, try this:

```css
#divProductDetailsModal {
  /*Position fixed to remain always on the view and keep dimensions relative to the browser window - expected behavior for modals*/
  position:fixed;
  
  /*width and height to any % value and max width to keep the dimensions you have on large screens*/
  width: 80%;
  max-width:1280px;
  height: 662px;
  max-height:80%;
  
  /*overflow show scroll when needed*/
  overflow:auto;
  
  /*Position element and center on screen*/
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  
  /*extra Look*/
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  border: 0;
}
#divProductDetailsModal img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="divProductDetailsModal">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/1024">
</div>
```